# String index out of range: -1 error with CFFeed

Tags: xml, coldfusion, rss, coldfusion-8

I have the following code in a basic .cfm file. I want to pull the RSS of the NYTimes Business feed.

```
    <cfset feedurl = "http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Business.xml">
    <cffeed source="#feedurl#" properties="feedmeta" query="feeditems" />
    <cfdump var="#feeditems#" label="feedItems" />
```

When I run this I get the following error -

```
    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException - in D:\nytimesrss.cfm : line 2
    String index out of range: -1
```

But the same code works fine with [the Washington feed](http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Politics.xml).  Is this a problem at the NYTimes end or is there something I can do to fix it?

Comment: I copy-pasted your first block of code and it's running fine for me on CF9. Maybe it was an intermittent issue?

Comment: (Edit) Worked for me too under CF10. Check the logs `{cf_root}\logs\feed.log`. Perhaps access is being blocked or throttled. Might check the site terms.

Comment: Wow thank you Sean and Leigh! I am still getting the error but that is an interesting find.

Comment: Has the code ever worked for you? Like @Leigh said, it's possible you may be blocked or throttled if you've been pulling the feed data all morning.

Comment: We are running ColdFusion 8 - I suspect that may be the issue then.

Comment: Sean - yes this code has been working fine for us for a long time and we use the code on a variety of feeds. It is just a random few NYTimes feeds that have been generating errors but then other NYTimes feeds are fine. :)

Comment: Check the logs. They might give you more insight about whether or not it is an intermittent connection issue. (I cannot remember if the `feed.log` exists in CF8).

Comment: I just checked - it doesn't exist under CF8. Gah!

Comment: Well check the others too (most recent timestamp). Maybe feed errors are recorded elsewhere. Also, do those "random" feeds fail consistently - or only some of the time.

Comment: I have no idea how to understand the logfile but this is what came up - String index out of range: -1 The specific sequence of files included or processed is: D:\jenelle\nytimesrss.cfm, line: 2

Comment: (Edit) In which log file? [There are several](http://mkruger.cfwebtools.com/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=A98FC11A-D423-2C94-321969FEDED489F4) and some contain more detail than others. (While it never hurts to check the logs, I do not know how much detail CF8 logs about feed errors. You may need to use a proxy)

Comment: This business one has been a consistent fail. I am going through and checking now as I think the others that have issues are to do with the advertisements in their feeds and the code we use on our design files to block them. So at the moment the business one seems to be the problem. The feed displays fine on its own at (http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Business.xml) which keeps bringing me back to it being our issue.

Comment: If it fails consistently, that strongly suggests throttling or a connection/firewall problem. You may need to use a proxy to inspect the actual http call. Might also try calling the feed url with `cfhttp` and dumping the response.

Comment: AHA! Could this be an issue? Alert: JVM memory allocation recovered to under 450 MB  - that one was from montior.log. The other error was from the application log.

Comment: BTW - thank you for all your help Leigh. Your responses really help me to understand what is going on! :)

Comment: I used `<cfhttp url = "http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Business.xml" method="get" timeout="5">
<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">` and all the data dumps into 'Filecontent' but the error details has `[empty string]`

Comment: Hm... I just tried it with CF8 and got the same error in CF8. Let me poke around the log files.

Comment: Well - I used that feed address on our own page with the code that we had to chage last year because of their ads and ... IT WORKS! So whatever happens with this feed when trying to dump it is one thing but, the feed is working. 
THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH FOR YOU HELP! @Leigh - you are a star!

Comment: *with the code that we had to change last year* Out of curiosity, what is the actual code? Feel free to post it as an "answer". I am guessing the old code does not use cffeed ..? Because in my tests the feed *retrieves* successfully, but there is something about it that cffeed does not like... (Glad you found a work around, btw :)

Comment: The answer should be posted as an answer, and the question updated with the relevant information from these comments. A long string of comments is hard for people to follow.

Comment: @Jen All of this should be in your question (you can edit your question using the 'edit' link below the question).  Putting it in comments makes it much harder to follow (and comments are subject to deletion at any time).

Comment: Thanks for the tip @GeorgeStocker - starting to edit now. :)

Comment: Sounds like you are now using different code to parse the feed, and the new error is related to that change. IF so, I would open a new thread (instead of mixing issues) and close this one. The answer to the original question seems to be that CF8's `cffeed` tag cannot parse that feed. However the issue appears to be resolved in later versions ie CF9/10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consensus is CF8's `<cffeed>` tag cannot parse the NYT's feed. However the issue appears to be resolved in later versions ie CF9/10.

Comment: It would help others to know what you ended up using instead. Did you grab the feed with `cfhttp` and then use `xmlParse(cfhttp.fileContent)`?

Comment: I've undeleted it - I just didn't want you wasting anymore of your time. :( ... as you can tell I'm kind of over it. :(